# How to use href with static file when deploy flask in windows server?

Tags: python, flask, fastcgi

When i have set file path in href tag like this `<a href="/static/file">` which is work normally in localhost but when deploy the application in windows server (FastCGI), it error because not found the file path, so what is a problem and how to fix it.

Comment: I think you should setup your server to handle the static files, not flask itself.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Flask` framework, I suggest in using `Jinja2` template mechanism which allows you to point what file you need to retrieve, present and etc., so in your case, you could write in the `HTML` template like this:

`<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='<file_path_after_static_dir>') }}">`

But for more information, I would offer to read official [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) on how to work with `Flask` and `Jinja2` templates.

> You have to have a proper [structure](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/) of `Flask` project in order to work properly with templates, static files, `Jinja2` template.